# OrderBy result of a LeftJoin in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to orderBy the result of query, but is not working, and my sort works just for one page.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = Person::leftJoin('registers', 'people.register_id', '=', 'registers.id');

    if ($request->has('sortBy')) {
        $query->orderBy($request->sortBy, ($request->has('desc')) ? 'asc' : 'desc');
    } else {
        $query->orderByDesc('people.id'); // if I comment this IF and remain just this row,still not working.
    } 

    return response()->json($query->paginate($request->per_page));

}
```

Comment: Not working is a very generic term please explain :) errors logs? unexpected results etc.

Comment: I fix first part. orderByDesc must be for people.register_id. , but the sortBy from request works just for one page, and not for whole data.

Comment: What is the value of `$request->sortBy`?

Comment: Is the name of the column. That I want to order asc/desc.